# How to guarantee the safety of couchDB in a Hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

A malicious actor/database administrator is able to manipulate data within CouchDB of all the peers within the network.

How can we guarantee the safety of the couch DB [other than below techniques] and how can this kind of scenario be prevented?

1. Provide appropriate permissions to couchDb
2. Provide appropriate endorsement policy

Also, CouchDB allows deleting the document. On querying the said peer, the peer returns null. How can this be prevented?

When a particular record is changed equally in all peers, Hyperledger fabric is unable to detect the attack. How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

Each peer has its own instance of couchDB to track the world state, and each one of those couchDB instances has their own credentials. In the peer's `core.yaml` configuration, specifically `ledger.state.couchDBConfig`, there are options for `username` and `password`. These set the admin credentials for peer <=> couchDB interactions. These usernames and passwords should be unique for each peer. That way, a malicious actor would need all of these credentials in order to corrupt the world state of all peers within the network.

Fabric offers protections within the framework of transaction flow for malicious peers via the configurable endorsement policies, as you note. They do not offer protection against someone gaining access to your server and retrieving/modifying credentials.